Best way to check multiple file types in Robot Framework
Have an automated test using robot framework to check for the presence of certain file types.
Up to now we've only been checking for .crt files, but I now need to check for either .crt or .pem files.
The check itself should be for either or both.
This is my current code:
${certs}=   SSHLibrary.List Files In Directory   ${cert_file_path}   *.crt

What's the easiest way to check for both the crt and pem file types in a single test?

  @{tmp}=     List Files In Directory    ${cert_file_path}
  @{files}=   Evaluate                   list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(('.crt', '.pem')), ${tmp}))

And then you change the ('.crt', '.pem') into extensions you like. Downside of this is that you are fetching all the filenames in the cert_file_path and doing the filtering on the robot side.. But at least it works.

Depends on what SSHLibrary  uses for pattern matching and im too bored to check the code now. On shell level one could use *.{crt,pem} so maybe this could work:
${certs}=   SSHLibrary.List Files In Directory   ${cert_file_path}   *.{crt,pem}


Unfortunately didn't work, but thank you. I suspect I'm just going to have to build a rather ugly 'if' clause into the test

yeah, another answer added that i tried and shoudl work.
